# AngularJS : Video tag not working with dynamic returned URL source

Tags: angularjs, html5-video, src

I'm getting url value and trying to bind with Video tag's src attribute, however video is not being displayed.

```
  <video width="400" controls="controls">
    <source ng-src="{{result.url | trustUrl}}" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

If I apply direct source value as string it's working fine. Say,

```
  <video width="400" controls="controls">
    <source src="videos/How_Does_AngularJS_Work_Beginners_Angular_Tutorial.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

I also tried sanitize, $sce filter for trusted URL.
My Filter

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('videoApp.filters')
  .filter('trustUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function (recordingUrl) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(recordingUrl);
    };
  }]);
})();
```

My Controller

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('videoApp.controllers')
  .controller('GetSingleVideoCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'VideoServices', 'AuthService', '$uibModal',
    function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, VideoServices, AuthService, $uibModal) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.result = {};
    vm.requestParams = {};

    vm.initialize = function() {
      var videoId = $stateParams.videoId;

      vm.requestParams = {
        'sessionId': AuthService.getSessionId(),
        'videoId' : videoId
      };
      VideoServices.getSingleVideo(vm.requestParams, vm.onGetSingleVideoSuccess, vm.onGetSingleVideosError);
    };

    vm.onGetSingleVideoSuccess = function(response) {
        $scope.result = response.data.data;
    };
    vm.onGetSingleVideosError = function(response) {
    };
    vm.initialize();
  }]);
})();
```

API Response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "_id": "57faefe60820a91ac042610a",
        "name": "Angular Video",
        "description": "How to use Angular.js to save time",
        "url": "videos/How_Does_AngularJS_Work_Beginners_Angular_Tutorial.mp4",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

In html please don't include the src.

In angular js, try this code,

```
$scope.player = videojs("player", {
        "controls": true,
        "autoplay": false,
        "preload": "auto",
        "loop": false
});
$scope.player.src({
        "type": "video/mp4",
        "src": "videos/How_Does_AngularJS_Work_Beginners_Angular_Tutorial.mp4"
});
```

Comment: Thanks, But it's not working. And I want to use dynamic value of src.

Comment: For me it is working, and i am using dynamic src using angular

Comment: Could you please add what will be there in View ?

Comment: View will only have <video id="player" class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered vjs-dotskin" ></video>

Answer (score 1):

Try without source tag

```
    <video width="400" controls src="{{result.url}}></video>
```